# Gravar o Nome de uma Coluna como item em outra Coluna

Tags: php, mysql

Seguinte, eu tenho uma tabela com vários valores e eu preciso comparar os valores de várias colunas, fiz isso com o PHP e consegui separar o maior valor, segue o código:

```
    while($aux = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{


    $cb = $aux['cb'];
    $rb = $aux['rb'];
    $lb = $aux['lb'];
    $rwb = $aux['rwb'];
    $lwb = $aux['lwb'];
    $cdm = $aux['cdm'];
    $cm = $aux['cm'];
    $rm = $aux['rm'];
    $lm = $aux['lm'];
    $cam = $aux['cam'];
    $cf = $aux['cf'];
    $rf = $aux['rf'];
    $lf = $aux['lf'];
    $rw = $aux['rw'];
    $lw = $aux['lw'];
    $st = $aux['st'];
    $Maior = 0;
    $arr = array($cb,$rb,$lb,$rwb,$lwb,$cdm,$cm,$rm,$lm,$cam,$cf,$rf,$lf,$rw,$lw,$st);
    foreach ($arr as &$value) {
        if($value > $Maior) {


            $total = $value;

        }
        $Maior = $value;

    }


    unset($value);    
}
    echo $total;
```

O que eu não estou conseguindo pensar de forma lógica é como fazer por exemplo, se o cf é o mais alto, como atribuir uma variável o texto 'cf' e com isso eu faria um insert em uma tabela, nesse filtro eu sei que o cf é o maior.

Comment: Sinceramente, seu código ta meio bagunçado, tem coisa ai que nem precisa, ta faltando bastante informações: O que são essas variáveis `$cb`, `$rb`, ...? O que é o `$total` e `$maior`? Pra que `unset($value);`? Qual o objetivo do código? Talvez o que quer pode ser feito direto no SQL

Comment: são os valores buscados pelo select que está acima do while, o objetivo é pegar o valor mais alto, quando encontrado ao invez de grava o valor eu quero gravar o nome da coluna, por exemplo "CF"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com esses 3 comandos você consegue o que quer:

- [**compact**](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.compact.php)— cria um array contendo variáveis e seus valores
- [**max**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.max.php) - localiza o maior valor
- [**array_search**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-search.php) - procura por um valor em um array e retorna sua chave correspondente caso seja encontrado

  ```
  $cb = $aux['cb'];
  $rb = $aux['rb'];
  $lb = $aux['lb'];
  $rwb = $aux['rwb'];
  $lwb = $aux['lwb'];
  $cdm = $aux['cdm'];
  $cm = $aux['cm'];
  $rm = $aux['rm'];
  $lm = $aux['lm'];
  $cam = $aux['cam'];
  $cf = $aux['cf'];
  $rf = $aux['rf'];
  $lf = $aux['lf'];
  $rw = $aux['rw'];
  $lw = $aux['lw'];
  $st = $aux['st'];

  $arr = array("cb","rb","lb","rwb","lwb","cdm","cm","rm","lm","cam","cf","rf","lf","rw","lw","st");

  $result = compact($arr);

  $maior =(max($result));

  $chave = array_search(max($result), $result);
  ```

[**veja exemplo no ideone**](https://ideone.com/7kCULU)

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia fazer a busca no array do próprio retorno e não criar um novo array. Dai teria a referencia de qual coluna pegou a maior.

```
$maior = 0;
$colunaMaior = '';
while($aux = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
  foreach($aux as $key => $value){
     if($value > $maior){
        $maior = $value;
        $colunaMaior = $key;
     }
  }

}
```